# Regex to match dot character occuring alone in a line

Tags: regex, bison, flex-lexer

A sentence containing a single dot marks the end of the required portion of a file. It may or may not be the EOF. If I use flex and bison to parse this file, how can I match this line using some regular expression? Or is there some other way? I cannot use "." in Flex grammar as it can come anywhere in any portion, may be as  a part of some word, mail id, etc.

Example: if my  input file is as shown:

This is a simple file for testing.
mail_id: abc@fgl.mn
date: 20.09.2011
here goes some lines of information.

.

[Here there can be more sentences].

I need to parse only till that line containing that ".". How can I do that?

Comment: any inputs or expected outputs?

Comment: what you asking is not clear just give inputs and your expecteds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression:

```
^\.$
```

will match a line containing just a dot. `^` matches the beginning of a line, `$` matches the end of a line.